# What is the exact purpose for spring.jmx.enabled?

Tags: spring-boot, jmx, spring-boot-actuator, spring-jmx

For Spring Boot (v2.4.2), in the [Monitoring and Management over JMX](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-jmx) section indicates:

```
Java Management Extensions (JMX) provide a standard mechanism to monitor and manage applications. 
By default, this feature is not enabled and can be turned on by setting the configuration property 
spring.jmx.enabled to true. Spring Boot exposes management endpoints as JMX MBeans under
the org.springframework.boot domain by default.
```

Therefore `spring.jmx.enabled` is *false* by default.

I don't understand this behavior, because for a quick SB app based on web with dev tools and actuator and even when is declared `spring.jmx.enabled` with **false** with and without `Dev Tools` and `Actuator` dependencies I always can see `org.springframework.boot` domain as follows:

- `spring.jmx.enabled=false` and with `dev tools` and with `Actuator`

[image]

- `spring.jmx.enabled=false` and without `dev tools` and with `Actuator`

[image]

- `spring.jmx.enabled=true` and without `dev tools` and without `Actuator`

[image]

- `spring.jmx.enabled=false` and without `dev tools` and without `Actuator`

[image]

**Observation:** I played around with and without Dev Tools and Actuator because I assumed that any of them were overriding internally `spring.jmx.enabled` to **true**, but it is not true as I confirmed for the latest scenario

So what should be the explicit difference to observe when `spring.jmx.enabled` is *false* and *true*? In the scenario shared above always appears the `org.springframework.boot` domain and I am able to access for all the scenarios shown above the management methods. I though that `spring.jmx.enabled` with false should **not** expose the `org.springframework.boot` domain from the beginning.

Comment: How are you launching the application? The presence of the `SpringApplication` admin bean tells me that it's being launched with `spring.application.admin.enabled=true` which is usually used by tooling.

Comment: I am executing the App through STS with the `Boot Dashboard` view. I did not configure explicitly the `spring.application.admin.enabled` property in none place

Comment: Documentation for this is appalling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you launch an application in STS it sets the `spring.application.admin.enabled` property to `true`. This enables MBeans in the `org.springframework.boot` domain that STS uses to manage the application and to provide insights into its functionality using information retrieved from the Actuator endpoints exposed over JMX.

Comment: So, to have the complete picture, and the reason of this confusion, if I execute the app in standalone mode (java -jar abc.jar) and no IDE involved the explanation available in the Reference documentation applies for that scenario, right?